# Get featured image url after publishing

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get the featured image url after a post is published but somehow it returns an empty URL.

But if I was to get the post_title, it is ok.

```
function update_google_map($post_id) {

    // If this is just a revision, don't send the email.


    global $wpdb;

    if (wp_is_post_revision($post_id))
        return;

    $post_title = get_the_title($post_id);

    $post_content1 = get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);
    $post_content = substr($post_content1, 0, 150);

    $post_url = get_permalink($post_id);

    $feat_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id));

    $google_location = get_post_meta($post_id, 'g_location', $single = true);

    $google_loc = explode(",", $google_location);

    $chk_result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id FROM wp_wpgmza WHERE post_id = '" . $post_id . "'");

    if (count($chk_result) > 0) {
        $wpdb->update(
                'wp_wpgmza', array(
            'description' => $post_content,
            'pic' => $feat_image_url,
            'link' => $post_url,
            'lat' => $google_loc[0],
            'lng' => $google_loc[1],
            'title' => $post_title,
            'map_id' => 1
                ), array('post_id' => $post_id), array(
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%s',
            '%d'
                )
        );
    } else {
        $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO wp_wpgmza (post_id, map_id, description, pic, link, lat,lng, anim, title, infoopen) "
            . "VALUES ('" . $post_id . "', 1, '" . $post_content . "', '" . $feat_image_url . "', '" . $post_url . "', '" . $google_loc[0] . "', '" . $google_loc[1] . "', 0, '" . $post_title . "', 0)");
    }

}

add_action('publish_post', 'update_google_map', 50);
```

If I was to update this same post with the save_post hook

```
add_action('save_post', 'update_map', 50);
```

in the Wordpress editor after publishing, I am able to get the featured image url again.  The same also apply to $google_location.  It is also empty when it tries to retrieve from postmeta table.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: I think the reason is because immediately after publishing, the featured image url is not ready yet.  Somehow I have to find another way to retrieve it.  Any suggestions on how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Please replace this code that you have used and check you have got feature image as `publish_post`

```
    function update_map($post_id) {

    global $wpdb;

    $thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id);
    $url = wp_get_attachment_url($thumbnail_id);

    if ($url != '') {
        wp_mail('abc@gmail.com', 'Yes', 'Yes');
    }

    wp_mail('abc@gmail.com', 'No', 'No');
}

add_action('publish_post', 'update_map', 50);
```

Because `$url` is not an array it's string so you can't use `!empty`

Comment: I have been working on this for the whole morning and I know it is not because of that.

Comment: that is not the issue, I am sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "wp_after_insert_post" hook.

```
add_action( 'wp_after_insert_post', 'after_insert_post', 10, 4 );

function after_insert_post( $post_id, $post, $update, $post_before ) {
if ( 'publish' !== $post->post_status||( $post_before && 'publish' === $post_before->post_status )||wp_is_post_revision( $post_id )) {
    return;
}
$image_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id);
```

}